# Strange behaviour of ElasticSearch with PHP-wrapper

Tags: php, apache, elasticsearch

I'm a very beginner with ElasticSearch, I wanted to try it out in my laptop. I just installed and used with [slimphp](http://www.slimframework.com/) with composer to load a client of the [official php api wrapper](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php).

The behaviour is the following:

I'm trying a simple get with the php-wrapper, everything works fine, but when I use Sense to run a PUT to update the document, if I try to retrieve the document via php again I get an empty `$response` and a `NULL` in `$response[_source]`, but if I try to GET it via Sense or command-line, I get the document without any problems.

It's like PHP can't get the ElasticSearch values, although if I index and get only via php-wrapper it works perfect (as far as I don't play with that documents outside the php-wrapper).

That makes me believe that elasicsearch is working good, but something is happening in my PHP or Apache or ES package.

I've posted the [issue on github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/308) but still we could not find any solution to the problem.

That is [the simple piece of code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/308#issuecomment-149942637) that should be working, but unfortunately it's not.

Some insights:

- I'm using Apache2 2.2.24 and PHP 5.6.14 with macports
- ElasticSearch php api version is 2.0.2
- Apache and ES logs doesn't give any clue
- The [empty response is actually a Guzzle object](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/308#issuecomment-149356696) with 200 response, but with a Resource Id body instead of the actual content.
- I'm using mod_php
- Mac osx 10.8.5

As my sysadmin knowledge is limited I'm out of ideas in what to investigate next, so I'm asking for some help here.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question, but I've had a lot of success with http://elastica.io/ for interfacing with ElasticSearch from PHP.

Comment: I just tried elastica, trying the same (getting via php, updating via sense and getting again via php) returns a elastica \Exception\NotFoundException for the updated document, which I can get via sense without problems. Thats crazy...

Comment: No clue. You're accessing the same instance/index in both cases?

Comment: I'm 90% sure about it. How can I check which intance or how many I'm running? Also, ps aux | ElasticSearch returns only one line.

Comment: It's curious that i cannot kill the PID of that process